# Cannot Edit ArcPy Script That is Within a Toolbox Using PyScriptor

Tags: arcpy, installation, arccatalog, pyscripter

There is a script within an ArcGIS toolbox (.tbx). The script must be within this toolbox due to company practices. I wish to edit a python (arcpy) script therein, Script1.py.

I must use PyScripter for this. The ArcGIS software and scripts are all held on a server that I cannot install new programs on; only PyScripter is available. I cannot navigate to scripts within the toolbox using PyScripter. When I attempt to through the PyScripter "open" dialogue, Toolboxes/.tbx do not show up as folders.

As such I have instead changed the "Script Tool Editor" and "Debugger" to point to the installation of PyScripter on this server (Geoprocessing -> Geoprocessing Options). However, now when I navigate to the script in ArcCatalog, right click and click "edit", nothing opens.

What is the error in my settings or my approach?

Comment: If they've installed ArcMap then that should have installed IDLE.  If you're stuck with PyScripter at present, have you considered looking for IDLE.  I occasionally use other Python IDEs like PySCripter, PyCharm but I find I'm more productive with IDLE, and it's always there.

Comment: IDLE, of the same python version as my Arcmap installation, is available. However I had the same issue: I cannot open scripts within toolboxes from IDLE and changing IDLE to be the "Script Tool Editor" and "Debugger" doesn't work; it doesn't open when I click "edit" on a script from within ArcCatalog. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: If your right click on the script tool in the toolbox and go to properties, what does it say in the source tab?

Comment: The Source is set to the location the tool was originally copied from. However I cannot change the Source to the new location, only to the toolbox where it is set, so I'm not sure how to proceed. This does give me an avenue to explore; thank you.

Comment: You can stick the `py` file that the tool interface points to into a folder where the `tbx` file is and then through the source tab properties simply repoint it to there. Then the IDE editor should pick it up.

Comment: Thank you, that works. If you'd like to add that as an answer I'll mark as such.